# Selenium + facebook php-webdriver: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to set up Selenium with the facebook php-webdriver. This is what I've done:

- Ran composer require facebook/webdriver to install the package
- Started the selenium server on port 4444 (default)
- Downloaded the latest 32-bit chromedriver from [enter link description here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.37/) (No separate 64bit available)
- Copied the chromedriver.exe to the project folder (don't know if this is necessary)
- Stated chromedriver. It runs on port 9515 by default.
- Ran the script to open a browser window in chrome.

In my script below, I get an error on the third line

```
$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'; // this is the default
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities);
```

The error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:15.31Z' System info: host: 'WINCOM', ip: '192.168.0.10', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '9.0.1' Driver info: driver.version: unknown in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\testnew\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Exception\WebDriverException.php:154 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\testnew\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor.php(320): Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverException::throwException(33, 'Unable to creat...', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\testnew\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.php(126): Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor->execute(Object(Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\WebDriverCommand)) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\testnew\test.php(11): Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhos...', Object(Facebook\WebDriver in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\testnew\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Exception\WebDriverException.php on line 154
```

In the Selenium terminal, I see this message:

```
14:18:08.607 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider:org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
```

Can anyone direct me on how to solve this. I've looked everywhere, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem, I have set correct PATH variable with driver files, tried running selenium version 3.3.1 to 3.12 but no hekp

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem.
It seems you should put the chrome web driver executable and your script in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Running geckodriver with root user I got the same problem.
Running geckodriver with same user than php scripts, it started to work.
You can try running both with unprivileged user.